# Can't connect to host on computers (wifi/lan) but works in Android Phone via wifi

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

So, I'm trying to connect to www.toshiba.pt, from Brasil. I've tested two computers and major browsers (Chrome, Firefox and IE), but I can't connect to it.

When I try using my Samsung Galaxy S4 I can connect to it, no problem, via the same wifi connection the computers are using. I was even careful of disabling 3G connections.

When I try to ping it from computers it returns a timeout. When I ping from phone, all times are ok. Traceroute looks ok, except for the last hop, which should be the host.

Here's what I've tried already:

- Checked and disabled firewall on computers (one of them doesn't have it anyway).
- Tried to run Combofix, ADWCleaner, Malware Bytes, Avira, etc, no
  luck.
- Tried to reboot into Safe mode, still no luck.
- Used wireshark to diagnose, but it doesn't receive any response.
- Connected the computers directly to the internet modem, bypassing wifi router.
- Reset tcp/ipv4 stack on windows
- Tried ping with dont-fragment and reduced payload to check for MTU problems
- Tried to telnet the host on port 80, no connection neither from phone or computers, but I can get it going on two VMs I own in AWS, one in N.Virginia and the other in Sao Paulo
- Tried from another computer, with Windows 7, located in another city in Brasil (via teamviewer) and worked.

So it looks like it's a problem with the internet provider. But what is bugging me is that the phone can connect through the same connection.

Tracert output on computers

```
C:\Users\Daniel Costa>tracert www.toshiba.pt

Rastreando a rota para tds.toshiba.eu [213.161.81.133]
com no máximo 30 saltos:

  1     4 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    14 ms    11 ms    12 ms  b3d25001.virtua.com.br [179.210.80.1]
  3    13 ms    13 ms    11 ms  c91120c2.virtua.com.br [201.17.32.194]
  4    15 ms    12 ms    15 ms  c9110007.virtua.com.br [201.17.0.7]
  5    19 ms    14 ms    15 ms  embratel-T0-2-0-0-uacc03.rjoen.embratel.net.br [201.30.79.9]
  6    16 ms    15 ms    15 ms  200.244.216.148
  7    13 ms    14 ms    17 ms  200.244.216.174
  8    15 ms   138 ms    16 ms  200.244.216.203
  9   127 ms   127 ms   121 ms  ebt-BP1223-intl03.mianap.embratel.net.br [200.230.220.58]
 10   127 ms   127 ms   127 ms  ae-7.r04.miamfl02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [157.238.179.177]
 11   136 ms   134 ms   191 ms  xe-0-1-0.mpr2.mia1.us.zip.zayo.com [64.125.13.117]
 12   231 ms   214 ms   342 ms  v94.ae29.mpr2.lhr2.uk.zip.zayo.com [64.125.30.105]
 13     *      212 ms   210 ms  ae10.mpr1.lhr1.uk.zip.zayo.com [64.125.31.193]
 14     *        *        *     Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
 15     *        *        *     Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
 16  ^C
```

Windows 7 64-bit on computers and Android 5.0 on SGS S4

Comment: Does http://www.toshiba.co.uk/ work?

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the tracert output

Comment: Can you do a `ping 8.8.8.8`? If this responds, then you are having an issue with DNS lookup.

Comment: It isn't DNS issue. As you can see from tracert output, when I query the fqdn, it resolves to the correct IP.

Comment: If you can't telnet to it on port 80 on any device, then you have a firewalling or ISP problem blocking it. That would suggest your being able to connect to it via the phone as a fluke, likely loading from cache. Given most Android phones have a hotspot function, connecting your computer through your phone would go a long way to ruling out your ISP.